# How to maintain JBoss Modules

Tags: java, jboss, dependencies, wildfly, jboss-modules

Recently, I have had to port an app from Tomcat to Wildfly and I'm currently working on setting up the modules directory for Wildfly.

It took a little bit of learning, but I figured out how to set up Spring, ActiveMQ RA, and several other libs as modules. This is working, but it has me worried about future maintenance of the modules directory. I have had to craft the entire directory by hand and I am worried about having to do this for every new dependency that every new app needs.

What are the best practices for maintaining JBoss Modules? Is the modules directory put into some version control system like SVN to detect and propagate changes?

Lets say I need a new framework in my app. From my understanding I would need to download the jars, create a modules directory for the jars, and then repeat this process for each environment in which I need Wildfly. What happens when needing to do this while other apps are running? This seems extremely time consuming in the long run.

I feel like there is a much better way to do this that I am either not realizing or too green with JBoss to understand.

With Maven and a pom, its so simple to hook up to a local or remote repo, and have the entire directory built out and available everywhere automatically. I feel like there must be something similar for JBoss Modules.

**At the heart of my question: How are others using JBoss Modules and maintaining it within a production environment? What resources should I read or utilize?**

Thanks for your time.

Kevin

Comment: Is there a reason you're installing modules over just including the dependencies in your WAR?

Comment: Well it seemed that any dependencies which are shared between webapps in the same container should be placed into a module. They also help a lot with issues arising from classpath problems and so I was starting to lean towards maintaining every lib within the modules structure. Would that be overkill? What should be a module? Is there some criteria that signals something should be a module?

Comment: It really depends. A module uses it's own class loader so if an application needs a unique context to the module that could be an issue. As far as adding modules you can use the CLI `module add` command so it could be scripted. Also make sure to read https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Class+Loading+in+WildFly.

Comment: Gotcha, the CLI option seems very promising, but you still have to go through the routine of tailoring the dependencies and ensuring you've got them correct. For now it seems, I will take it slow and add only as I need. One question I have though, I want to store my modules directory in some sort of SVN repo, do you see any downsides to this approach other than memory constraints? I can't think of anything wrong with it and am wondering if I'm not thinking it all the way through.

Comment: I've got no idea on the SVN thing. I guess I don't really see an advantage to it honestly. I'm not sure what you gain by having a history of changes for it.

Comment: The real benefit would be for the module.xml, which can get tricky to set up properly for large frameworks. I've run into issues whose solutions were not very obvious (the stack trace is not always helpful for modules) and that sent me down a long winded path only to find out that I accidentally removed a 'services=import' clause for a small dependency. The benefits are slim to be sure, but it would be nice to know a certain 'version' of my modules worked and to be able to revert back to that 'version'. I could see the argument of it being overkill, but I'd rather have too much than too little

Answer (score 0):

I'm also looking for a solution for this.

I have previously been in projects where the JBoss CLI is being used. But I dont like that. It adds complexity as the JBoss CLI scripts are something new that developers need to understand. Changes in files are easier to understand.

I'm thinking of this:

- Put a directory in a git-repo that has the exact directory structure as JBoss version used.
- `standalone-full.xml` is put in `git-repo/jboss-eap-6.4/standalone/configuration/standalone-full.xml`
- `module.xml`-files is put in `git-repo/jboss-eap-6.4/modules/system/layers/.../module.xml`

Also a `setup.sh` that will:

- Copy the files from the git-repo to the installation directory of JBoss.
- Download any jar-files, needed for the `modules.xml`, from a configured Nexus server. And put them into correct `modules`-directory.

The benefits are:

- No binary files in git.
- Changes to configuration of JBoss can be tracked.
- The setup can be a part of a bigger scripted setup of for developers or docker images...